# New model insert overwriting others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application where I have two models called *Column* and *Row*:

Column:

```
has_many :rows

accepts_nested_attributes_for :rows, :reject_if => lambda { |b| b[:data].blank? }
```

Row:

```
belongs_to :column
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_for [@table, @row] do |f| %>

   <% @columns.each do |column| %>
       <%= f.label :data %><br>
       <%= f.text_area :data %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and my create action in the controller:

```
@row = Row.new(row_params)

if @row.save
  redirect_to table_rows_path, notice: 'row was successfully created.' 
else
 render action: 'new'
end
```

and my new action:

```
@columns = Column.where(:table_id => @table.id)
@row = Row.new(id: @table.id)
```

So I have two problems. The first is if I have say two columns, so there will be two textfields on the new row page, and I enter "Test" in the first text field and "Another Test" in the second. The only thing that is getting saved is the second. The first one saves "Another Test" instead of "Test".

Also, how can I get the row (which belongs to a column) to save a column_id inside each row?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Please share your controller `new` action that renders this form.

Comment: @vinodadhikary, Ok I just updated my answer

Comment: and what is `@collection`?

Comment: @vidodadikary, Sorry that was me messing around and forgot to change it, should be `@table`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Did you mean "update my question"?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, Oops, yeah I did

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the new Row's id to the `@table.id`. Take that out; you never need to create a new .id. Then use `column_id: params[:column_id]` to link them up.