# Create with multiple params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
def new
   @columns = Column.where(:table_id => @table.id)
   @row = Row.new(id: @table.id)
end

def create

   row_params.each do |row_param|
      @row = Row.new(row_param)
      @row.column_id = params["column_id"]

      if @row.save
         redirect_to collection_rows_path, notice: 'item was successfully created.' 
      else
         render action: 'new'
      end
   end
end
```

I have a form that looks like:

```
<%= form_for [@table, @row] do |f| %>

   <% @columns.each do |column| %>
       <%= column.id %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :column_id, column.id %>
       <%= f.label :data %><br>
       <%= f.text_field :data %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, I'm trying to send multiple params and have them inserted with the column. But I keep getting this error:

`undefined method`stringify_keys' for ["data", "No"]:Array` when there is two columns which means there is two text fields and I insert "Hello" in the first one, and "No" in the second.

Two things: Why is it only reading the "No" on the second one instead of both the "Hello" and "No"? And also why am I getting this error?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. It is only reading "No" which is your input in the last "Data" text_field since the two text_fields generated in your form_for save their input value in the same params key which is params[:row][:data]. What happens then is the latest value saved to the params[:row][:data] key overrides any previous value it had.
2. The error `undefined method stringify_keys' for ["data", "No"]:Array` happens because you create 2 text_fields with the same name which is :data. When you submit the form, an Array is being submitted instead of a String that Rails expects when using text_field.

Solution to your problem:

This seems like an ideal use case for using a nested model form. Basing on your code, it looks like Row belongs_to Table. So in your Table model you'll need to add this code:

```
#app/models/table.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :row
```

Then add the following code in your RowsController:

```
#app/controllers/rows_controller.rb

def new
  @columns = Column.where(:table_id => @table.id)
  @columns.each do |column| 
    @table.rows.build(column_id: column.id)
  end
end

def create
  @table = Table.new(table_params)
  if @table.save
    redirect_to collection_rows_path, notice: 'item was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
def table_params
  params.require(:table).permit(rows_attributes: [:data, :column_id])
end
```

Then in your 'rows#new' view:

```
#app/views/rows/new.html.erb

<%= form_for @table, url: rows_path ,method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :rows do |r| %>
    <%= r.object.column.name %>
    <%= r.hidden_field :column_id, value: r.object.column_id %>
    <%= r.label :data %><br>
    <%= r.text_field :data %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What the above code will do is allow you to create multiple rows for a column according to the number of columns the table has. This won't work though if a @table has no @columns yet. This assumes that you've created @columns for the @table already. Basing on your code though, it seems like that's already what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this still save a column_id for each row? The row corresponds with the column, so how could I also get the column name next to the row in the form?

Comment: I've just updated my answer to show the column.name in the form for each row and to include the column_id in the form submission

Comment: Thanks again. But I get an error from `@table.rows.build(column_id: column.id)` that says `unknown attribute: table_id`

Comment: It doesn't seem like Row belongs_to Table since you got that error. What is the association between rows, tables and columns? If Row is supposed to belong to Table, you should have a table_id column in rows.

Answer (score 1):

you want to store 'data' as array in Row

In Rails model Row add

```
 serialize :data, Array
```

in view

```
text_field_tag 'row[data][]'
```

You are getting only 'No' because form for does not know its an array so , it picks the last one And you are getting this error because rails does not know you want to store it as array , it excepts a string but got an array instead.

Comment: Thanks Anil for the answer. But as soon I did this I got a `Missing template rows/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}` error

Comment: i think you didn't set up relation very well ..have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/20752904/1970061 it might help you.